# When should I use JSF components and when should I use html tags?

Tags: html, jsf

I would like to design a webpage using JSF.

Some parts of the page I can layout using `<h:panelGroup>` and `<h:panelGrid>` or, instead, I can use `<p>`, `<div>`, etc instead.

Just wondering which is preferable for best practices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you don't need the features provided by the JSF tag, I'd prefer to use plain HTML.

For example, `<h:panelGroup>` has a `rendered` attribute that allows you bind to a backing bean boolean variable to conditionally display the output, but with a `<div>` or `<span>`, you cannot do this.

The `<h:panelGroup>` will by default generate a `<span>`. If you prefer a `<div>`, then you can use `<h:panelGroup layout="block">`. It will generate a `<div>`for you .

Comment: The first sentence sums it all up. It's less overhead as well.

Comment: I've found that the `<h:panelGroup/>` tag without the `layout`, `style` or `styleClass` attributes renders neither a `<div/>` nor a `<span/>`. It can be useful purely as a way to show/hide sections of the page using the `rendered` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Just recent case from my practise:

**1.** for `<p>` and `<div>` you can't use `rendered` attribute

**2.** make your code more structural and solid - to be easy-readable for other users of your code

Answer (score 3):

There is a recommendation to not mix up jsf with html. Background: Then your jsf page can be rendered as something different than html. But as far as I know up till now there are only renderers for html (although you can write your own).

In practice I found it hard to follow this recommendation and ended up mixing html and jsf, e.g. for headings or line breaks I use html.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, I use a mix betweek HTML and Facelets tags in the layout pages. But for the actual content pages I try to only use the JSF tags available with my JSF library of choice (JSF + RichFaces).

That way I can have more control of which elements to show and hide, as well as the contents within each element, but I can still hard-code my main page layout in the facelets template file.